# Change color of specific bar in a chart base on returned data

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way to change the color of a bar in a barchart base on a returned value from ajax?
This is the code that I am following and modifying.

```
var stocksDescription = [];
    var stocksRemaining = [];
    $.ajax({
        type : "get",
        url : "getDashboardStocksData",
        data : {'foo' : 'foo'},
        success : function(data){
            stocksDescription = data[0];
            stocksRemaining = data[1];

            var e = document.getElementById("barChartSimpleGradientsNumbers").getContext("2d");

            gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 200, 0, 50);
            gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "rgba(91, 175, 231, 1)");
            gradientFill.addColorStop(1, hexToRGB('#30f033', 0.8));

            var a = {
                type: "bar",
                data: {
                    labels: stocksDescription,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Remaining",
                        backgroundColor: gradientFill,
                        borderColor: "#30f033",
                        pointBorderColor: "#FFF",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "#30f033",
                        pointBorderWidth: 2,
                        pointHoverRadius: 4,
                        pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
                        pointRadius: 4,
                        fill: true,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        data: stocksRemaining
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        bodySpacing: 4,
                        mode: "nearest",
                        intersect: 0,
                        position: "nearest",
                        xPadding: 10,
                        yPadding: 10,
                        caretPadding: 10
                    },
                    responsive: 1,
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            gridLines: 0,
                            gridLines: {
                                zeroLineColor: "transparent",
                                drawBorder: false
                            }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                            display: 0,
                            gridLines: 0,
                            ticks: {
                                display: false
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                zeroLineColor: "transparent",
                                drawTicks: false,
                                display: false,
                                drawBorder: false
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                    layout: {
                        padding: {
                            left: 0,
                            right: 0,
                            top: 15,
                            bottom: 15
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            var viewsChart = new Chart(e, a);
        }
    });
```

The returned **data** from ajax is from a controller

```
public function getDashboardStocksData()
{
    $stocks = Stocks::all();
    $stocksDesciption = array();
    $stocksRemaining = array();
    foreach ($stocks as $key => $value) {
        array_push($stocksDesciption, $stocks[$key]->description);
        array_push($stocksRemaining, $stocks[$key]->quantity);
    }
    $data[0] = $stocksDesciption;
    $data[1] = $stocksRemaining;

    return $data;
}
```

the sample returned data :

```
stocksDescription = ["Stock 1", "Stock 2", "Stock 3", "Stock 4" "Stock 5"];
stocksRemaining = [100, 26, 9, 45, 6];
```

With this, there is nothing wrong with the code, I just want to change the bar color of that specific stock if the remaining quantity is below 10. I want to make it color red.

The code is fired upon refresh of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
        let dataSet = [100, 26, 9, 45, 6];
        let labels = ["Stock 1", "Stock 2", "Stock 3", "Stock 4", "Stock 5"];
        let barBg = Array.from({'length': dataSet.length}, (_, i) => dataSet[i] < 10 ? 'red' : 'green');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels:  labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Stocks',
                    data: dataSet,
                    backgroundColor: barBg,
                    borderColor: barBg,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha256-xKeoJ50pzbUGkpQxDYHD7o7hxe0LaOGeguUidbq6vis=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
  <canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="50"></canvas>
```

You can use `backgroundColor` prop to fill each bar, create a array that hold bar color on the basic of each stock value, where value is less than 10 set color red in array for that particular index.

Comment: Thanks bro. I made some modifications based on what I needed. Thanks for this idea. Cheers!